# Correct usage of "sogar" and "einmal" to mean "even"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, usage, adverb

I would appreciate any clarification on the correct usage of *sogar* and *einmal* as translations of the English word "even" when used in the following sense:

> He didn't drink anything...not even the beer!

I believe this is properly translated as *Er hat nichts getrunken...nicht einmal das Bier!*

Is that correct?  If not, should I use *sogar* instead?  If so, when would one properly use *sogar* instead of *einmal*?

Comment: It's correct. I am still too bleary-eyed to say when you could not substitute _einmal_ for _sogar_.

Comment: Obviously, word order must change. _"... sogar das Bier nicht"_ becomes _"... nicht einmal das Bier"_. Thus _einmal_ is the adverb of choice for English speakers as they can stick to their accustomed word order :)

Comment: Note that you can only use the entire prase "nicht einmal" in this case - "einmal" by itself can never mean "even".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

"Not even" can be translated with "nicht einmal" or "sogar nicht":

> He didn't drink anything … not even the beer.
>
> Er trank gar nichts … nicht einmal das  Bier.
>
> Er trank gar nichts … sogar das Bier nicht.

"Even" in positive use cannot be translated with "einmal" but with "sogar":

> He drank everything … even the milk.
>
> Er trank alles … sogar die Milch.
>
> NOT: Er trank alles … einmal die Milch.

Comment: spot on answer :)

Comment: Sorry, I'm a little confused... to me, "sogar nicht" sounds very strange if not outright unidiomatic. I'd have said "even" = "sogar"; "not even" = "nicht einmal". Am I wrong?

Comment: "sogar nicht" is probably not used as often as "nicht einmal" or "selbst nicht", but it does occur.

Answer (score 0):

It probably depends on which "feel" you are going for. To me, *sogar* sounds more casual, whereas *einmal* feels formal. Also, *einmal* can't be properly used in positive, I think.

"Not even once" could use *sogar* or *einmal*.

"Even this week" would use *sogar* the best, not *einmal*.

Comment: Bitte benutz die  Buttons zur Auszeichnung (kursiv, fett) und die Vorschau zur Kontrolle, ob es hübsch formatiert ist. Als Sprachbereich legen wir auch Wert auf Details wie Großschreibung am Satzanfang und Satzzeichen. Außerdem ist auf Begrüßungs- und Endfloskeln ("Hope it helps, D") zu verzichten.